# Is there a way to pass a variable to a AbstractComposeView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-custom-view

I have a custom view in jetpack compose but I want to pass additional data. I tried to create additional variable but it has a lint error.

> Custom view `BlendedPhotoView` is missing constructor used by tools:
> `(Context)` or `(Context,AttributeSet)` or
> `(Context,AttributeSet,int)`

Here is my class

```
class BlendedPhotoView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
    val photoUri: String?
) : AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        BuildBlendedPhoto(photoUri = photoUri)
    }

    fun capture(view: BlendedPhotoView) {
        val bitmap = ImageUtils.generateShareImage(view)
        ShareUtils.shareImageToOthers(context, "test", bitmap)
    }

}
```

Comment: just add default parameter `val photoUri: String? = null` to silence this warning.

Comment: that worked, I dont understant why though can you give an explanation

Comment: This warning says that one of three default constructors should be implemented. Most probably these are required in case you need to create your view from XML - as it won't be able to pass `photoUri` in your case. I guess it's safe to suppress this warning if you don't plan to use this view from XML.